# webpack and react recognise css class names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a React component that I am trying to import the css.

```
import './Example.css';

class Example extends Component {
  return <div className="example-class">Example</div>
}
```

My file structure looks like this

```
build
  -index.js
src
  -index.js
  -Example.css
```

My `webpack.config.js` looks like the following.

Currently everything builds, but the css doesnt appear to be getting picked up.

Can anyone see what I would need to do to access my classnames after build?

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [ 'css-loader' ]
    }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    'react': 'commonjs react'
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any error. What happens currently

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it doesnt recognise the css

Comment: In which folder are your css files located

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri updated the question

Comment: can you try to add `context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')` in the webpack code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `css-loader` only processes the CSS but does not make it available in the browser. You can use [`style-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) for this, which injects the CSS into a `<style>` tag. (see also [Loading CSS](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css))

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
}
```

Another possibility is to extract the CSS with [`extract-text-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin). It will extract the CSS and create a `.css` file in addition to your JavaScript bundle. You can then include the CSS in your HTML.

Comment: You just helped me get my first piece of code released to npm! cheers man! check it out and give it a star if you like ;-) https://pau1fitz.github.io/react-slidez/

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import styles from './Example.css';

class Example extends Component {
  return <div className={styles.example-class}>Example</div>
}
```

Comment: i think there is an issue with the `-`